# why is the size(array) bigger then the array it self

Tags: php, html, image, upload

to explain my problem in more detail: when uploading several images I get the size from the image array via sizeof ($ _ FILES ['imgs']); and with this number i make a for loop to give details of the pictures. but I get several errors: Warning: Undefined array key 3 in C: \ xampp \ htdocs \ projetcs \ en \ upload.php on line 30. I don't know why can you help me?

[error image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8aQTY.png)

website code:

```
  <body>
<?php
  session_start();
  if(!isset($_SESSION["MAIN"])){
      //Header("Location: ./login.php?for=upload");
      //exit();
  }
  if(isset($_POST["upload"])){
    //require '../utils/sql.php';
    //$stmt=$mysql->prepare("INSERT INTO DEALS (USER, TITLE, DESCR, COST, IMGS, ST) VALUES ()");
    var_dump($_FILES['imgs']);
    $max = sizeof($_FILES['imgs']);
    echo $max;
    for($i = 0; $i < $max-1;$i++)
    {
      ?><br/><?php
      echo($_FILES["imgs"]["name"][$i]." ,  ".$_FILES["imgs"]["type"][$i]." ,  ".$_FILES["imgs"]["tmp_name"][$i]." ,  ".$_FILES["imgs"]["error"][$i]." ,  ".$_FILES["imgs"]["size"][$i]);
    }
  }
 ?>
  <form class="" action="./upload.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <div class="input-group mb-3">
      <div class="input-group-prepend">
        <span class="input-group-text" id="inputGroup-sizing-default">Title</span>
      </div>
      <input type="text" class="form-control"  aria-describedby="inputGroup-sizing-default" required>
    </div>

    <div class="input-group">
      <div class="input-group-prepend">
        <span class="input-group-text">Beschreibung</span>
      </div>
      <textarea class="form-control" style="resize: none;"required></textarea>
    </div>
    <div class="input-group mb-3">
      <div class="input-group-prepend">
        <span class="input-group-text">€</span>
      </div>
      <input type="text" class="form-control"  required>
      <div class="input-group-append">
        <span class="input-group-text">,00</span>
      </div>
      <select class="custom-select" id="inputGroupSelect01" required>
        <option value="FP">Festpreis</option>
        <option value="VB">VB</option>
      </select>
    </div>
    <div class="input-group mb-3">
      <div class="input-group-prepend">
        <span class="input-group-text">Upload</span>
      </div>
      <div class="custom-file">
        <input type="file" name="imgs[]" multiple class="custom-file-input" id="inputGroupFile01" required>
        <label class="custom-file-label" for="inputGroupFile01">Choose file</label>
      </div>
    </div>
    <button type="submit" name="upload" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg btn-block">Hochladen</button>
  </form>
```

Comment: Because you are taking the count of the top level (which has 5 elements), but you iterate the inner arrays which have only 3. Just use `foreach` instead.

Answer (score 0):

You're defining `$max` the size of the root element of your `$_FILES["imgs"]`, while it should be the size of one of the inner elements, for example `tmp_name`.

Also, make sure that when you loop, you don't subtract 1 from the $max value, as you would lose 1 element.

So it should be something like this

```php
$max = sizeof($_FILES['imgs']['tmp_name']);
echo $max."<br />";
for ($i = 0; $i < $max; $i++) {
    echo "<br />".($_FILES["imgs"]["name"][$i]." ,  ".$_FILES["imgs"]["type"][$i]." ,  ".$_FILES["imgs"]["tmp_name"][$i]." ,  ".$_FILES["imgs"]["error"][$i]." ,  ".$_FILES["imgs"]["size"][$i]);
}
```

Finally, **please note that `session_start` can not be placed after any output**. It should be the first thing in your .php script, way above any HTML tags like `<body>` or even `<head>`